# How can I draw an arrow in gnuplot such that its over the axis?

Tags: gnuplot

I am drawing an arrow in gnuplot by setting it before the plot command:

```
set arrow from graph -0.01, first cutOff-0.001 rto graph 0.02, first 0.002 lc rgb "blue" lw 5 nohead 
plot ...
```

but it appears under the axis (i.e. the black axis is visibly over my arrow - line in this case). How can I reverse it, so that the arrow (line) is above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure that I understand your question.  To me it sounds like your axis is being plotted after the arrow, so anywhere that the axis intersects the arrow appears black (the assumed axis color) instead of blue (the arrow color).  If that is the case, you should try adding `front` to your set arrow command.

e.g.

```
set arrow from graph -0.01, first cutOff-0.001 rto graph 0.02, first 0.002 lc rgb "blue" lw 5 nohead front
```